# Importing configuration class without @Configuration in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I don't know if it is supported or not, but I accidentally `@Import`'ed a Spring configuration which didn't have `@Configuration` on it. As a result, I got a mysterious cyclic dependency error which clearly not the case (or at least I am unable to recognize it). This is the error message, which I don't really get:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'beanC' defined in URL[jar:file:/Users/ghornyak/work/dev/sandbox/spring-boot-tutorial/build/libs/gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/hello/BeanC.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'hello.config.TestConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'beanB' parameter 0; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'beanA': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
```

This is a simplified example: both `BeanB` and `BeanC` depends on `BeanA` and `BeanA` and `BeanB` are defined in the `TestConfig` class missing the `@Configuration` annotation.

The source of the configuration:

```
package hello.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import hello.BeanA;
import hello.BeanB;

public class TestConfig {

    @Bean
    public BeanA beanA() {
        System.out.println("Creating beanA");
        return new BeanA();
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public BeanB beanB(BeanA beanA) {
        System.out.println("Creating beanB: " + beanA);
        return new BeanB();
    }
}
```

The definition of `BeanC`:

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class BeanC {

    public BeanC(BeanA beanA) {
        System.out.println("Creating BeanC: " + beanA);
    }
}
```

The test application:

```
package hello;


import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;

import hello.config.TestConfig;

@SpringBootApplication
@Import(TestConfig.class)
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = Application.class)
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Now, if I mark the config with the `@Configuration` annotation the error goes away and everything works as expected.

So the question is, should imported configuration classes have the aforementioned annotation on them? If so, then why isn't the absence of it indicated with an error?

Answer (score 3):

Yes that is expected, you cannot call bean inside another bean definition in the same class unless you annotate that class with @Configuration, the reason behind this is cglib which creates the AOP proxy that spring needs to reference and call the beans

> Typically, @Bean methods are declared within @Configuration classes.
>   In this case, bean methods may reference other @Bean methods in the
>   same class by calling them directly. This ensures that references
>   between beans are strongly typed and navigable. Such so-called
>   'inter-bean references' are guaranteed to respect scoping and AOP
>   semantics, just like getBean() lookups would. These are the semantics
>   known from the original 'Spring JavaConfig' project which require
>   CGLIB subclassing of each such configuration class at runtime. As a
>   consequence, @Configuration classes and their factory methods must not
>   be marked as final or private in this mode

check this [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html)

Comment: I am not user if it is related to my problem, I don't reference the methods as it is mentioned, just use `@Autowire` on the method parameters.